# how to set view on window in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi friend  my application was crash by doing this what the problem in my code
i got this error message Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
              ///  ************** This is for create  the  sqlite  data base**************** \\\

                                  [BaseModal copyDatabaseIfNeeded];
    //self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    CheckForUpdatesModal *CFUM = [[CheckForUpdatesModal alloc]init];
    [CFUM sendRequest];
    [CFUM release];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(CallingtheSplashScreen:)
                                                 name:@"uniqueNotificationName"
                                               object:nil];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    return YES;
}
-(void)CallingtheSplashScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    SSView = [[[SplashScreenView alloc]initWithNibName:@"SplashScreenView" bundle:nil]autorelease];
   // self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    SSView.Progrestotal = [[[notification userInfo]valueForKey:@"SUM"]intValue];
    [self.window addSubview:SSView.view];
   // self.window.rootViewController=SSView;
   // [[self window] setRootViewController:SSView];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ 
    NSLog(@"Rahul"); // Here you can define your code to execute in  background.}); self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Comment: i am using notification bec i have to call firstmy modal class CheckForUpdatesModal for getting value on background then i have to view controller can u help how can i handal both

Comment: Yes, You can use NSTimer or Dispatch_synch to execute any code/function in background. Try with it.

Comment: I have edited my answer use that code it will work to to get value in background.

Comment: hi i try ur code but it not working proper i call my CheckForUpdatesModal in dispatch_async it call only my sendrequest method it not calling -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection when i put here breakpoint it not call my breakpoint at this menthod